How to create a magnifying glass on Flet (python)
This is my first time writing on stackoverflow. I am quite new to programming, and I did start learning a bit of Flet, since Python was the first thing I learned and I feel more comfy.
I dont know how to do it, and thats why I ask here... I do have an image that is changing everytime pushing a button, and I would like to have a magnifying glass effect when I hover over picture... Any clue how to do it or where to start?
Thanks!
I did try but I dont know where to start.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
